# C# double not working as expected

Tags: c#, double

I understand that a double is a decimal.
In the following program the output is 1 even though I thought it would be 1.05 repeating.

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
double d = 19 / 18;
Console.WriteLine(d);
Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Am I misunderstanding double?

Comment: You are misunderstanding integer math:
`Integer-19` divided by `Integer-18` results in a Integer: `1`.  Try `19.0 / 18.0`

Comment: "I understand that a double is a decimal" - not really. It's a binary floating point number, although that's not the problem you've got. Your actual problem is you're performing integer division, then converting the result (an integer) into a double...

Comment: [C# Reference Division Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Come on, millions of times asked and answered....

Comment: `double d = 19 / 18;` -> `double d = (double)(19 / 18);` -> `double d = (double)(1);` -> `double d = 1.0d;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding integer math.

```
Integer-19 / Integer-18 results in an Integer with value 1.
```

(that you assign the value to a double is not relevant.  The calculation results in an Integer).

To fix it, use:

```
double d = 19.0 / 18.0;
```

Comment: or  double d = 19d / 18d;

Comment: @Xela or `double d = 19.0 / 18` or `double d = 19 / 18.0` or `double d = 19d / 18` or `double d = 19 / 18d` :)

Comment: or overkill double d = Convert.ToDouble(19) / Convert.ToDouble(18); lol